# Rails display older data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Very strange problem. I have a rails site, which works normal in the past of a few years. After migrating it to a new server, a very strange problem started to appear.

The data displayed on the view is always older data set. I have to restart the rails server in order for the view to be updated and display the latest data set.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: We'll need more info on this one. Is there some kind of caching involved in your app? Does resetting the browser cache yield up-to-date data on the next page reload? What is your infrastructure, e.g. which webserver are you using? During the upgrade, did you change the Ruby version? The Rails version? The operating system?

Comment: It is not browser problem. It is server problem. It is rails 3 site. Using passenger to serve the site. Ruby version is:ruby 2.1.2p95. I think the ruby version got updated for the new sever. In the before it was Ruby 2.0. OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Please adjust the tag ruby-on-rails-4 to 3 then. Does the problem occur on all resources or just on one? What are the caching mechanisms that you use server side?

Comment: Thank you Raffael, I have little experiences in server caching. How i mess around of the rails caching? Thanks!

Comment: Just changed this  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false